# Npm link library doesn't link or get a reference when building in my main project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

So I am trying to build locally but doesn't seem to work during the npm install, what do you think could be the issue?

Let's say I have a lib project here:

npm ls

**cwd is: /Users/my/git-main5/eclipse/setup/decouple/vue-lib/lib**

@my/vue-components@1.2.3 /Users/my/git-main5/eclipse/setup/decouple/vue-lib/lib

I do npm install

**npm run build**

**npm link**

Now I want to reference this version 1.2.3 in my main project

**pwd
/Users/my/git-main5/eclipse/setup/decouple/myapp/app**

npm link @my/vue-components@1.2.3
Or
npm link @my/vue-components

**npm install**

```
Error
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @my/vue-components@1.2.3
```

...

If I run npm ls, seems to list it

npm ls -g (this technically is wrong)

├── @my/vue-components@1.2.3 -> ./../../../Users/my/git-main5/eclipse/setup/decouple/vue-lib/lib

But this is right:

npm ls
├── @my/vue-components@1.2.3 -> ./../../vue-lib/lib

Still can't find that reference to the local library.

```
package json:

{
  "name": "@my/vue-components",
  "version": "1.2.3",
  "files": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build && npm run test:unit  && cp ./coverage/clover.xml ./test-report.xml && cp ./coverage/lcov.info ./",
    "bundle": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name 'bd-vue-components' ./src/components/index.js",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit --no-cache"
  },
```

Comment: Have you tried using [local paths](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#local-paths)?

Comment: I tried local but then says can't use public paths and ends in endless loop.  This should be simple?